# Ember JS: "Uncaught #<error>" from {{#each}} statement

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I keep getting an 'Uncaught #error" message in my console when I run a specific route on my ember app. It doesn't seem to affect anything, but why is it there?? I've isolated it to an {{#each}} statement, but can't see what's wrong with it and again, the code works seemingly flawlessly. Here are the relevant snippets:

index.html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="blog/index">
<h4>Recent Posts</h4>
<table class="table">
{{#each}}
    <tr><td>
    {{#link-to 'blog.post' this}}
        <h4>{{title}} <small class="muted">by {{author}}</small><h4>
    {{/link-to}}
    </td></tr>
{{/each}}
</table>
</script>
```

App.js

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('blog', { path: '/blog' }, function () {
        this.route('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' });
    });
});

App.BlogIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('post');
    }
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr(),
    author: DS.attr(),
    date: DS.attr(),
    excerpt: DS.attr(),
    body: DS.attr()
});

App.Post.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Rails in Omakase',
        author: 'd2h',
        date: new Date('12-27-2012'),
        excerpt: 'This is an excerpt',
        body: 'This is my body!'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        title: 'The Parley Letter',
        author: 'd2h',
        date: new Date('12-24-2012'),
        excerpt: 'This is an excerpt',
        body: 'This is my body!'
    }
];
```

Like I said, if I remove the {{#each}} statement, then there is no error message in the console, but if I do add it, it works fine and gives me such an error. what am I doing wrong exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is missing its `<tbody>` tag

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    {{#each}}
      <tr></tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/30/ember-1-5-0-and-ember-1-6-beta-released.html